# Where is "save password" from WebView stored?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

I'm using the In App Browser to open a website. When entering information into forms on websites, the IAB (the webview), asks if it should remember the username and password for next time.

If the user answers yes to this - where is the username and password stored? Is it stored outside of the app container, and is it safe?

Comment: This happens on Android.

Comment: All the user settings including the passwords are synced to the app specific database and it is safely sandboxed.